# NotificationCenter registered selector is not called

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter

I currently have this code below to see if the day has elapsed, but it doesn't seem to be working. Have I coded this correctly?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:"calendarDayDidChange:", name:NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged, object:nil)

func calendarDayDidChange(notification : NSNotification) {
    // code to respond to notification
}
```

Comment: Put breakpoint and test.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @meaning-matters After testing my app the next day, the code doesn't get called?

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: @meaning-matters Later in my code, the "workoutCount" is used to reset a label to 0 which it has not done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you registered observer is not correct. Please try the below and check.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.calendarDayDidChange(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged, object:nil)
```

Comment: Good catch, "calendarDayDidChange:" (looks like Obj-C and) is never going to work indeed.